# What is the fastest way to send two subsequent HTTP requests?

Tags: performance, sockets, http, post

I am making a "username swapper" script that swaps my username from one online account to another with as little delay as possible. The first POST request releases the username from one account, and the subsequent POST request grabs the username on another account.

If there is any delay or mishap, even for a second, one of the many bots (known as "username autoclaimers") will snatch the username from me. There are many such bots on websites such as Instagram and Twitter where rare usernames are considered valuable and have a high monetary value.

I have thought of a few ways to optimize request speed:

- Re-use the same TCP connection for both sessions
- (Maybe?) use a lower-level library such as sockets for better speed
- Run the script on a low-latency server next to the webserver's location
- Wait for webserver maintenance or something until the bots break
- Use HTTP over HTTPS if the website does not require it for more speed

Are there any notable ways to improve speed or do I have most of it down?
 One thing I am not sure about is the language. Would a lower-level language such as C++ over Python have a difference in performance for something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main performance costs are due to the latency of the network and the time the server actually needs to handle the request (i.e. database lookups ...). Costs due to the choice of programming language or library are mostly irrelevant in this context.

The main costs with network are the TCP handshake and (with HTTPS) the following TLS handshake. These can be eliminated if the second request reuses the same underlying TCP connection - but of course the server actually needs to support this.

The time needed to handle the request by the server is not in control of the client. Apart from that there might be additional problems, like the server requiring the client to solve a captcha if some kind of automation is detected or that there are procedures in place which will make a quick reuse of a username impossible in order to fight misuse like selling usernames etc.